# Does the modern definition of "awful" come from its homonym to "offal"?

Tags: etymology, shakespeare, homonyms

The following lines are found in Act I, Scene III of *Julius Caesar*:

> What trash is Rome,
> What rubbish and what offal, when it serves
> For the base matter to illuminate
> So vile a thing as Caesar!

To my ears, the pronunciation of "offal" sounds very much like that for "awful", and this made me wonder if this homology contributed to the modern definition of the word "awful".

Comment: It's probably better to use *homophone* rather than *homonym* -- it's less ambiguous (although *homonym* has a suitable definition, it's not the only one).

Comment: Why was the etymonline post removed?

Comment: Twain used "Offal Court" as the address of Tom Canty (the Pauper) in The Prince and the Pauper. I reckon he was going for the double entendre there.

Comment: no.  Just a fun pseudo-connection.

Comment: DV for the capricious award

Comment: @ChrisH offal /ˈɒfəl/ and awful /ˈɔːfəl/ are neither homophones nor homonyms.

Comment: @NicholasShanks as I say in my answer. But the OP thought they sounded the same so meant *homophone*. In fact in some accents they do both sound like the IPA you've given for *awful*.

Comment: Could Shakespeare write or what??!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add a bit to the other good answers...

Although the OED notes that the word *awful* means "*Objectively*: awe-inspiring"<sup>1</sup>, the earliest (c885<sup>2</sup>, approximately 500 years before the advent of *offal* into the language<sup>3</sup>) attestation for *awful* is actually in the sense

> 1. Causing dread; terrible, dreadful, appalling.

This sense of the word has been in continuous use ever since. The earliest semi-positive sense of the word is not attested until c1000, and even then it is more in the sense of "scary" than "awesome":

> 2. Worthy of, or commanding, profound respect or reverential fear.

It is not until the mid-17th century that we get the sense

> 3. Solemnly impressive; sublimely majestic.

(And slightly earlier—by the end of the 16th century—we have the sense "filled with awe", definitions 5 & 6.)

This entry of the OED has not been fully updated, but I suspect that senses 3, 5, and 6 will be listed as now rare or obsolete when it is updated.

By the start of the 19th century, we have examples of the sense

> 4. a. *slang* Frightful, very ugly, monstrous; and hence as a mere intensive deriving its sense from the context = Exceedingly bad, great, long, etc.

which may be the most common meaning nowadays, and which I take to be the subject of the question. However, this seems to be a fairly straightforward expansion of the original sense of the word, rather than inspired by the word *offal*. Compare *terrible* (inspiring terror), *horrible* (inspiring horror), *dreadful* (inspiring dread), and *tremendous* (inspiring trembling) and their adverbial forms, which acquired their colloquial and intensifying usages around 1500, 1500, 1700, and 1800, respectively without any homophonic influences.

---

<sup>1</sup> "awful, adj." *OED Online*. Oxford University Press, March 2017.
<sup>2</sup> At this time the word was actually *ęgefull*, an Old English cognate of the word which became our modern *awful*; however, the two root words (for *awe*)

> were practically treated as dialectal variants of the same word, of which aye was still used in s.w. c1400, while awe was in the n.e. c1250. The sense-development is common to both. They are therefore here taken together; the examples being separated into groups α(from Old English ęge) and β(from Old Norse agi).
>   ("awe, n.1.")

<sup>3</sup> First attested ▸a1398. ("offal, n. and adj.")

Answer (score 37):

Not really.

**Awful** and **awesome** have the same root: *[awe](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=awe&allowed_in_frame=0)* (dread).

*[Offal](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/offal)*'s root is "off." Literally.

(Dictionary.com)(Etymonline)

Comment: Yes the derivation is from awe.The meaning of Awful has changed over the centuries and used to mean full of awe as in full of wonder rather than dread.  For example 17th century C16 refs praising the work of Wren on St Paul’s Cathedral.  See e.g.: http://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/10/31/st-pauls-cathedral/

Comment: That dictionary definition of "offal" is nonsense. I gather that the USA has strange ideas about not eating the "icky-looking" parts of animals, but there's nothing "inedible" about brains, hearts, lungs, etc. In fact in my part of the UK, pig spinal chord was a local speciality, when people used to fatten and kill their own pigs rather than buying frozen meat. (The same basic recipe is still on sale, but emasculated for tourists to the point where it's hardly worth eating any more).

Comment: @alephzero Apparently not just Americans; Shakespeare uses offal alongside rubbish to unfavorable characterize Caesar.

Comment: @MikeRoger I love the idea of amusing, awful, and artificial being used as positive adjectives. I do myself occasionally use 'awful' to describe a particularly sublime experience, though obviously 'awesome' is less confusing to my company.

Comment: Of course Shakespeare and Wren are the only possible citations here; shows how small the elite of our language's history is.

Comment: @alephzero  Is that a major or minor  spinal **chord** ?   :-)

Answer (score 20):

No, because they're not homophones in the accents that matter (in addition to the etymology).

In some (especially American) accents, they are homophones, but from oxforddictionaries.com (which prefers British pronunciation:

- [offal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/offal) /ˈɒf(ə)l/
- [awful](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/awful) /ˈɔːf(ə)l/

The experts may correct me but see [cot-caught merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot%E2%80%93caught_merger). While this occurs in some British English (Scotland) and Irish English, it's at all not common in England.  Whether it was in Shakespeare's time is a different question.

We can try to address this: [Shakespeare's Accent: How Did The Bard Really Sound?](http://www.npr.org/sections/monkeysee/2012/03/24/149160526/shakespeares-accent-how-did-the-bard-really-sound)  is an article from NPR reporting on a British Library project.  In the famous scene from Act II, scene II of Romeo and Juliet, Natalie Thomas as Juliet clearly pronounces the vowel in *not* in a way which could be distinguished from that in *caught*, *naught* etc. (unfortunately lacking in the clip -- the closest is probably *nor*).

Comment: Even as a native speaker of American English, there is certainly a difference in how I pronounce the initial syllable of these two words. It is subtle and might be munged if I were speaking especially quickly, but it is certainly there.

Comment: @CodyGray [this map](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/Cot-caught_merger.png) of the merger in the US might be interesting then. From the same wikipedia article I linked in the answer. Any implication that all Americans merge the two sounds was unintentional

Comment: Many Americans (like me) who don't merge *cot* and *caught* still merge *offal* and *awful*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offal) gives two pronunciations for *offal*, so it can rhyme with either *falafel* or *lawful*.

Comment: @PeterShor I suspected that a more specific merger existed, but I don't know if it has a name

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

People have humorously connected the two words for at least 150 years:

See [The Scrap Book and Magazine of American Literature, Volume 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=8v_VAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA77&dq=%22offal%20smell%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwionMjf6Y3TAhUCbSYKHVmeCeYQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22offal%20smell%22&f=false) (1862):

> Why is it unpleasant to have carrion near ?
> Because it makes an offal smell.

Also in:

[Harpers](https://books.google.com/books?id=eOeE3OgUy3gC&pg=PA819&dq=%22offal%20smell%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwionMjf6Y3TAhUCbSYKHVmeCeYQ6AEIMjAF#v=onepage&q=%22offal%20smell%22&f=false) 28 December 1861

and a similar joke in [More puniana](https://books.google.com/books?id=0joCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA190&dq=%22offal%20smell%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwionMjf6Y3TAhUCbSYKHVmeCeYQ6AEIHjAB#v=onepage&q=%22offal%20smell%22&f=false) (1875)

and

In the [Sydney Punch](https://books.google.com/books?id=v4E3AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA143&dq=%22offal%20smell%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwionMjf6Y3TAhUCbSYKHVmeCeYQ6AEIKDAD#v=onepage&q=%22offal%20smell%22&f=false) 24 September 1864,

Titled "Truly Awful", there is a joke about a man sticking his nose in Mt. Vesuvius:

> he would experience an offal smell

According to [Humorous English](https://books.google.com/books?id=6qMNAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%20offal%20smell%22&dq=%22%20offal%20smell%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi66vGU74_TAhWG2yYKHawqCWEQ6AEIRDAJ) (1961):

> Many definitions are little more than the play between a word and its **implied homonym**, like the explanation of a hobo as a road's scholar, the movies as reel life, or carrion as something having an **offal smell**.

However, Samuel Johnson's 1768 [dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=bXsCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT7#v=onepage&q=offal&f=false) says that Shakespeare uses "awful" (originating from awe + full) and "offal" (originating form off and fall) with almost opposite meanings:

> AWFUL...2. Worshipful; invested with dignity *Shakesp.*
>
> OFFAL...4. Any thing of no esteem *Shakesp.*

Comment: I'm astonished (not "surprised," as the other grammar pedants would jump on me) that this answer got the checkmark, seeing as it doesn't address the root question (pun intended).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I was only expecting an upvote or two, not a change of the accepted answer.  I might feel obligated to add more to answer.

Comment: @DavePhD Accepted? Ah, fixed now. :)

Comment: Puns and wordplay lasting through a century is good evidence that the words *aren't* etymologically connected. If the words were connected, it would hardly be worth making a joke! Bad joke: Why are authors always correct? Because they're write handed! Worse joke: Why is Mr. Right always correct? Because he's right handed!

Comment: Are you're saying that the modern meaning of  *awful* is in some measure attributable to *offal*? The last sentence in your recent edit doesn't clear up this issue.

Comment: @Mari-LouA no, there is no connection other than humor as far as I know

Comment: This is very country dependent. Where I live, the two words are so different that the joke at the top of this post would not work.

Comment: @Mari-LouA what do you think of the line in this book "I saw your campfire and the coffee smells offal good" https://books.google.com/books?id=dGMSAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT15&dq=%22smells+offal+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl6Laj94_TAhWMNiYKHXdDAAYQ6AEIPzAH#v=onepage&q=%22smells%20offal%20%22&f=false Is that accent, humor, or mistake?

Comment: Mistake, ignorance, spellchecker mishap, the next line has *...carried a riffle by his side...* I mean, riffle? C'mon, what is happening to the language and to spelling! Unless... a *riffle* does not mean a "rifle". PS retracted downvote.

Comment: @Mari-LouA George Washington spelled it with two "f"s.  "Infantry and Riffle Men" and several other instances in this collection of his writings  https://books.google.com/books?id=jjYOAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA393&dq=%22riffle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP98aNjpDTAhVFKCYKHRUqBcEQ6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=%22riffle%22&f=false Maybe that was the original spelling.